# Cumulative averages of a single column

Tags: scripting

I have a data file in column with values:

```
7.61718
7.71791
7.83437
8.04401 
8.16084
```

... until 64176th row

I need to calculate the cumulative averages:

average of first row 
average of first + second row 
average of first + second + third row ... and so one

I have tried multiple ideas with, but nothing worked well.

Comment: so you need to calculate average of all  64176 row values? Elaborate your "average of first row" - you can't take average from one single value

Comment: I wish I need only that... I need:  
7.61718/1 = 7.61718 
(7.61718 + 7.71791) /2 = ... 
(7.61718 + 7.71791 + 7.83437) /3 =... and so one

Answer (score 6):

Fast **`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ sum += $1; print sum/NR }' file
```

Comment: It is a sum of whole column, not for rows as I wanted.

Comment: @karogawa if you're now saying that your data has multiple columns which need to be summed before averaging the cumulative row totals then edit your question to say so.  and include sample data & example output which shows that.

Comment: @karogawa, your later claim contradicts with your current question.